# The missing links: link added before migration did not result in entries on the Linked sidebar

Tags: bug, migration, linked-questions

Sequence of events:

1. I asked [this question at Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/does-president-trump-have-a-global-campaign-to-decriminalize-homosexuality-in-t).
2. I added a link to [this question at Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/what-has-trump-done-to-oppress-the-lgbt-community) (shortly prior to migration).
3. My question was migrated to [this question at Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59061/what-steps-has-president-trumps-global-campaign-to-decriminalize-homosexuality).

After migration, I would expect the two questions at Politics.SE to be linked via the Linked sidebar.  However, neither are linked:

> [image: the missing link]

So I submit this as a report of this unexpected behavior.